# Polymer properties are not known in listener method

Tags: polymer, listener, polymer-1.0, web-component

Recently I encountered the following problem:

In my Polymer-based project I have a custom element, let's call it `<test-element>`. This element as `px-rangepicker` as a dependency, which is basically just a date picker. If you select a date from that picker, the event `px-datetime-range-submitted` is fired. Inside my `test-element` I have a listener for that:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'test-element',
    properties: {
      test: {
          type: String,
          value: "foobar"
      }
    },
    listeners: {
      'px-datetime-range-submitted': '_onDateRangeChanged'
    },
    _onDateRangeChanged: function(changeEvent) {
      console.log(this.test);
    }
});
```

Now, when I enter the site and `test-element` is loaded for the first time, the `_onDateRangeChanged` method is called. So far everything is okay. But: 
Console just sais `undefined`. No property is accessible from inside that method. The strange thing is:

```
console.log(Polymer.dom(this));
```

will give me a complete `DomApi` output as expected, with my property as a node:

```
▼ DomApi {node: test-element}
  ▼ node:test-element.iron-selected
    ► $: Object
      test: "foobar"
```

I can't help how this can happen - any help or info is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Update:**

See [the code at GitHub](https://github.com/sebastianroming/so-polymer-listener-question) and [a working example here](http://webmonkey.io/so-polymer-listener-question/) (the `px-datetime-range-submitted` event is called 5 times and console output is `undefined`).

Comment: From  the looks of your code the error must be somewhere else. Please provide more code and/or a fiddle to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: For real - I don't have any other code inside my `test-element`. I removed everything except this, but still can't access the properties. If I surround

Comment: That is really strange then

Comment: That's why I'm posting this here ;-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yytzymej/1/ here is a fiddle with a working example please add the datepicker thing. Second link is a guide how to get your dependencies working with fiddle: https://polygit.org/

Comment: Updated ms question, put some working code on GitHub and added a working example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi by your given example the problem is not your code or the code of the datepicker. Its just how polymer works.
Why does this happen?
The [px-rangepicker](https://github.com/PredixDev/px-rangepicker/blob/master/px-rangepicker.html) implements a behavior called [px-datetime-range-behavior](https://github.com/PredixDev/px-datetime-common/blob/master/px-datetime-range-behavior.html) within it there is an observer `_notifyRangeChanged(range.*)` which gets triggered by a change of the range property also this observer fires the `px-datetime-range-submitted` event. This property has a default value which means that its value gets filled at creation time of the component and also triggers the observer. And that seems to be done before the properties of your own component are initialized which then is still undefined. But after that when you open the picker and choose another date its triggered again and then the test property is filled with `foobar`.
To prevent anything bad happening just check if the value of test is set.

```
_onDateRangeChanged: function(changeEvent) {
  if(this.test !== undefined) {
       console.log(this.test);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's right, but I don't understand how a "static" property is undefined in this case, even when I output `Polymer.dom(this)` at the same time - and THERE my properties aren't undefined.

Comment: Sry can´t explain this. Have you tried to read the variable with `this.get('test')` get should be a general function from polymer.

Comment: I did, same result. It's undefined.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it that way now - not really what I wanted to have, but it's okay for now.

Comment: Cool sry that i couln´t help more!